# Rendering CSS on the Server Sid of my ReactJS Application using webpack on entry.js file

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

I am building a ReactJS App and on reload on localhost:8080/extension, the styling on the page flickers.  From what I understand this is being caused by the CSS being rendered on the Client side.

So what I am trying to do is in the entry.js file(I am using webpack), remove the require('./css/base.scss') from the if(document === 'undefined') block into the ReactDOMServer.render callback in order to compile the CSS on the server side.

Any tips or suggestions of how to render the css on the server side of the react application?

Thank You

Comment: What's your webpack build process look like?

Comment: Running npm run webpack, which builds the modules, serves from entry.js through webpack, which creates a build.js. Did you want to know exact loaders? or did this answer your question? @PAckerman

Comment: I think you can use a SASS loader in your webpack process to compile the css as part of your build. Then you'll have a precompiled CSS file to use.